# Struts hello world example

Tags: servlets, struts

I have a specific doubt.

In the example,[hello world example](http://www.dzone.com/tutorials/java/struts/struts-tutorial/struts-tutorial-using-eclipse-1.html) As soon as I enter the URL in the browser, does the control go to the action servlet or the index.jsp page? I'm confused because in the web.xml the welcome-file is the index.jsp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When ever the request comes from the browser the struts controller(ActionServlet) will     checks the `url-pattern` of  `*.do` from `servlet-mapping` tag in `web.xml`.

Every request should come to `web.xml` before to process mappings. Based on mappings it goes next to `struts-config.xml` file to which action or form should call.

you can look into this [Simple Struts Login Application](http://javabynataraj.blogspot.com/2011/12/basic-struts-login-application.html)

Answer (score 2):

Only `*.do` is mapped to ActionServlet. So, only the urls ending with `*.do` will go to ActionServlet.

Comment: And the control from ActionServlet will go to the HelloWorld.jsp? I'm drawing a sequence diagram for this example.